# Saving multiple rows to database

Tags: php, html

I have a table with an unknown number of rows. I'm trying to save edits to a checkbox field, select field and text field.

Here's a sample of what a table row looks like (generalized):

```
<tr onMouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE'"onMouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">
    <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[][item1]" value="118">
    <td><a target="blank" href="www.link.com">Link</a></td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input value="" type="text" name="batchupdate[][item2]" size=35></td>
    <td>
        <select name="batchupdate[][item3]">
        <optgroup label="Group 1">
            <option >1</option>
            <option >2</option>
            <option >3</option>
            <option >4</option>
            <option >5</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 2">
            <option >6</option>
            <option >7</option>
            <option >8</option>
            <option >9</option>
        </optgroup>
        </select>                           
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="FALSE" name="batchupdate[][item4]"></td>
</tr>
```

The "id" (item1) is the auto incrementing field in my postgresql database.

Here's the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['savebutton'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['bachtupdate']) || is_array($_POST['batchupdate']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['batchupdate'] as $i)
        {   
            $item1 = $i['item1'];
            $item2 = $i['item2'];
            $item2 = pg_escape_string($item2);
            $item3 = $i['item3'];

            if(isset($i['item4'])){
                $item4 = "TRUE";
            } else {
                $item4 = "FALSE";
            }

        $query = "UPDATE schema.table SET field2='$item2', field3='$item3', field4='$item4' WHERE id='$item1'";

        $result = pg_query($database, $query);

        if ($result) {
            // success
        } else {
            die("Error: " .pg_last_error());
        }
```

There's some other logic after this, but the query part is where it fails. I get an error that basically item3 and the id (item1) are empty, so it cannot find the row to update. Items2 and 4 work fine and I can see what they contain in the error message provided by postgres.

I found this solution online and adapted it to my own use. I'm just confused as to why some of the fields work and others don't. Ideas?

EDIT:

This is what the output looks like with echoes (inside the foreach loop). I commented out the postgres query. Notice that it does it twice. I also noticed that the checkbox isn't returning true. However, all the information is there...,

118 (id),
Text box 1,
Option 2,
FALSE (checkbox)

119 (id),
Text box 2,
Option 3

118 (id),
Text box 1,
Option 2,
FALSE (checkbox)

119 (id),
Text box 2,
Option 3

EDIT:

Next I'm going to try one of the following:

1. Use php to create name attributes that are unique (`item11`, `item12`, `item13`, etc), and increment a `for` loop that counts how many rows in the table there are, change the variables and perform the query. This seems way too messy, but I can't think of anything else...,
2. Instead of doing a `foreach`, do a `for` loop as seen in other examples I've found. Not sure what it will change, but it's worth a shot I guess.

I'll report back what I found.

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the SQL you're generating to see what's in there? Have you checked to make sure that `$_POST` contains the right values?

Comment: Just did this, the select field still doesn't pass anything, but the "id" does, the number 118. The weird thing is that the select field is allowed to be empty, so it's not that (even though it shouldn't be empty), the id should be an integer. Error I'm getting is that the id field is not an integer in the query.

Comment: I think I can fix the latter problem - lose the quotes around `'$item'`, and have it as `WHERE id=$item1`. Could you also try making one of the `<option>` entries a default, by adding `selected` to it? I can't see why it's not passing anything into $_POST!

Comment: The option field actually queries the database and adds "selected" to what's currently in there. What's shown above is the HTML output of several functions.

Comment: Here's what I get when I remove the quotes: `Error: ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...ign SET field4='FALSE', field2='1', field3='' WHERE field1= ^`

Comment: It looks like it's not getting anything for field1, which is why you're getting that error. Could you try a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of the parsing code, so I can see exactly what's being submitted?

Comment: Yep, It looks like this with one row of content: `array(3) { ["batchupdate"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["item1"]=> string(3) "118" } [1]=> array(1) { ["item2"]=> string(10) "TEXT FIELD" } [2]=> array(1) { ["item3"]=> string(3) "OPTION1" } }  ["editButton"]=> string(8) "Save All" } array(3) { ["batchupdate"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["item1"]=> string(3) "118" } [1]=> array(1) { ["item2"]=> string(10) "TEXT FIELD" } [2]=> array(1) { ["item3"]=> string(3) "OPTION1" } }  ["editButton"]=> string(8) "Save All" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How generalized is the HTML you show?

I mean, when you write

```
 <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[][item1]" value="118">
```

You do place something in the first key of batchupdate, do you not?

Because otherwise the POST will send out, say,

```
batchupdate[][item1]=118&batchupdate[][item3]=124...
```

which will create TWO DIFFERENT ROWS in batchupdate[], one with item1, the other with only item3, since [] is autoincrement syntax.

Each "group" of rows should have a different ID as the first index:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[row1][item1]" value="118">
 <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[row1][item2]" value="119">
 <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[row1][item3]" value="120">
 ...
 <input type="hidden" name="batchupdate[row2][item1]" value="123">
```

This will result in one entry of batchupdate with item1,2 and 3 defined and equal to 118, 119, and 120, which seems what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh really? Like I said, I found this from a random forum post after searching from the web. So if I don't know how many rows of content I'm going to have in my table, how can I make sure one row (the form above) all goes into the same `batchupdate[row#]`. If I get what you're saying, even though this is one row of content linked here, I'm actually putting eatch `<input>` into it's own row of the array?

Comment: Yes. If you send a simple GET with test[]=a&test[]=b, you will receive an array() holding [ 0=>a, 1=>b ]. It stands to reason that were you to submit test[][a]=b&test[][c]=d, you would get [ 0 => [ a => b ], 1 => [ c => d ] ], and not [ 0 => [ a => b, c => d ] ]. To have all in the same row, you need specify the first index: test[0][a]=b&test[0][c]=d. You can generate this index while rendering the form.

Comment: I haven't built it yet, but I think this is the answer I've been looking for.